# Calculate the adjoint of a derivative of the function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, adjoint-operators

If

> > $\partial_{x}\psi = \psi_{x} + \psi \partial_{x}$,
> >
> > and when we apply $^{\dagger}$ on both sides, then
> >
> > $(\partial_{x}\psi = \psi_{x} + \psi \partial_{x})^{\dagger},$
> >
> > $-\psi^{\dagger}\partial_{x} = \psi_{x}^{\dagger}-\partial_{x}\psi^{\dagger}, \quad \partial_{x}^{\dagger}=-\partial_{x}.$
> >
> > Is it right?

Comment: Of course. It is best if you rewrite your last line to look like the first line!

Comment: Delete question, now?